# How do I properly initialize a late variable

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, initialization, dart-null-safety

I have a late property(`_bmi`) set to null by default and then I initialize it in a method `calcBMI()`, after its initialization, I use its value in two more methods, `result` and `interpretation` to fulfill some bool conditions, but I run into a `lateinitialisationerror`, because the first method (`result()`) doesn't recognize the value I initialized in `calcBMI()`, it rather defaults to the initial null value that the `_bmi` property had, however the `interpretation()` method recognizes the initialized value. How I know it's only the first method that doesn't recognize it is coz when I pass a value to the `_bmi` property when I'm setting it, the app doesn't throw the error, it works, but then it uses the set value for the first method, but the initialised value from `calcBMI()` for the second method, what am I doing wrong, here is the code.

```
class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({required this.weight, required this.height});

  int weight;
  int height;
  late double _bmi = 30; // when I set this value, result() works with it, but interpretation() works with the value passed in calcBMI();

  String calcBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String result() {
    if(_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'overweight';
    } else if(_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'normal';
    } else {
      return 'underweight';
    }
  }

  String interpretation() {
    if(_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'You have a higher than normal body weight. Try to exercise more.';
    } else if(_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'You have a normal body weight. Good job.';
    } else {
      return 'You have a lower than normal body weight. You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }

}
```

this is where I use my class

```
BottomButton(
              onTap: () {
                CalculatorBrain calc = CalculatorBrain(
                  weight: weight,
                  height: height,
                );
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return ResultsPage(result: calc.result(), bMI: calc.calcBMI(), interpretation: calc.interpretation());
                        }
                    ),
                  );
                });
              },
              title: 'CALCULATE',
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got a `LateInitializationError` before, it's not that "[`result()`] doesn't recognize the value I initialized in `calcBMI()`", it's that you called `result()` before you called `calcBMI()`.

Giving `_bmi` an initial value avoids the `LateInitializationError`, but you still have the same fundamental problem: you're reading `_bmi` *before* you call `calcBMI()` to assign it the value you actually want.

In particular, you have:

```dart
return ResultsPage(result: calc.result(), bMI: calc.calcBMI(), interpretation: calc.interpretation());
```

Dart evaluates function arguments in left-to-right order, so you'll call `calc.result()` first, then `calc.calcBMI()`, and then `calc.interpretation()`.  Changing the order should fix your problem:

```dart
return ResultsPage(
  bMI: calc.calcBMI(),
  result: calc.result(),
  interpretation: calc.interpretation(),
);
```

However, relying on argument evaluation order would be poor style.  It would not be  obvious to readers (including your future self) that argument order matters.  It would be much better to explicitly order operations that are order-dependent:

```dart
var bmi = calc.calcBMI();
return ResultsPage(
  result: calc.result(),
  bMI: bmi,
  interpretation: calc.interpretation(),
);
```

Note that this has nothing to do with `_bmi` being `late`.  Declaring `_bmi` as `late` provides no purpose in your code as currently written, and you could just remove it.  But you also should consider rewriting your code to make `CalculatorBrain` less dependent on consumers calling its methods in a particular order.  Some possibilities:

### Compute `_bmi` dynamically

You could make `_bmi` a getter that computes the correct value for `weight`/`height` on every access:

```dart
class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({required this.weight, required this.height});

  int weight;
  int height;

  double get _bmi => weight / pow(height / 100, 2);

  String calcBMI() => _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);

  String result() {
    final _bmi = this._bmi;
    if(_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'overweight';
    } else if(_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'normal';
    } else {
      return 'underweight';
    }
  }

  ...
```

### Compute `_bmi` exactly once

If you make `weight`/`height` `final`, then you can compute `_bmi` once and be done:

```dart
class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({required this.weight, required this.height});

  final int weight;
  final int height;

  // `late` computes `_bmi` lazily, which is necessary because it depends on
  // `weight` and `height`.
  late final double _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);

  ...
```

### Update `_bmi` automatically if `weight` or `height` changes

If you `weight`/`height` must be mutable, then you could create setters so that `_bmi` is always updated automatically:

```dart
class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({required int weight, required int height})
    : _weight = weight,
      _height = height {
    _updateBmi();
  }

  late double _bmi;

  int _weight;
  int get weight => _weight;
  set weight(int value) {
    _weight = value;
    _updateBmi();
  }

  int _height;
  int get height => _height;
  set height(int value) {
    _height = value;
    _updateBmi();
  }

  void _updateBmi() {
    _bmi => weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

late modifier means that you will at some point define it, which you are doing in `calcBMI()`, after which you call `interpretation()` where `_bmi` already has a value.
Your code would crash if you just call `result()` since `_bmi` still isn't defined.

Comment: so, _bmi only gets a value after I call calcBMI(), anything I call before calcBMI() defaults to the null value of _bmi

Comment: Correct. Which can be dangerous. I would do some checks before handling _bmi.